# Finding the truth value of a quantified statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

The problem reads:

> Let $\text{isFatherOf}(x,y)$ be "$x$ is the father of $y$" and the domain $D = \{\text{all people now living or who have lived}\}$. Find the truth value of the quantified statement $\forall x \, \exists y \, \text{isFatherOf}(x,y)$.

The answer given is "False" but I'm not sure how to come to that answer. Would it be best to write out the statement in an English sentence or use a formulaic method to determine the truth value?

Comment: Because Not all men become fathers (there are men, with no $y$ of which they are the father); and women never become fathers, hence all women are such that they are not fathers of anyone.

Comment: All that is needed to prove this example is to find one person who is living or once lived, that fathered no one.  Then we have that it is **not the case** that ever person  x, there exists/existed someone y, who was fathered by x.  Personally, I am a person, now living, for which there is no person y, such $isFatherOf(amWhy, y)$

Answer (score 0):

Translating it into English is always a good idea to get some better sense of the statement.

This particular statement translates to 'Everyone is (or was) the father of someone'

I think you can see why this is false.